# Can I reduce the html font size during responsive?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I did the whole website with **rem units** as I used **bootstrap 4 aplha version** and now am going to start doing responsive of the website.

I have `html {font-size: 16px}` so I need to know that can I reduce the size of the `html` in **media queries**? Something like:

```
/****responsive css***/
@media only screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
    html{
        font-size: 15px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
    html{
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
```

I need to know that is there any problem with this or I can use this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way you may overwrite the rule in a **Lower than 1280px** device width, because tha latter rule will override it.

You would better do it like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    html{
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
    html{
        font-size: 15px;
    }
}
```

also, that would be a better idea to use `%` (Percentage units) combined with `em` unit, which are [relative CSS units](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html) for size, in a responsive design, as it is not no more dependent on the **device pixel ratio**.

```
body{
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

#element{
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

You may read more about **Best practices about CSS units** [here](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/css2em.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Provided it's not overwritten, e.g. on the `body`, it should work

Also, the rest of your font-sizes will need to be in `rem`, `em` or `%`

Anything that is in `px` will remain that way

Comment: thanks for quick response ,i used font size, margin,padding etc in rem so can i used this approach as i said in question.

Comment: No problem. If that's the case, then I don't see why it wouldn't work. However, in most cases, you'd be better specifying margin and padding etc in `%` so the site is fluid